# Lc3: How do I compare two values?

Tags: int, compare, lc3

I am trying to write an lc3 assembly language problem but I am pretty stuck. The program must take in two digits and output which digit is larger. I am required to use a subroutine to accomplish this.
Now, I am putting the first digit in r1, the second digit in r3, and i have to put the output in r0. I am really confused as to how I should compare these 2 values, any advice would be appreciated!

```
.ORIG X3000

;********************MAIN***********************
LEA R0, IN_STR               ;DISPLAYS STRING
PUTS  
GETC                         ;INPUT NUM1
OUT
ADD R1,R0,X0                 ;PUTS NUM1 IN R1
GETC                         ;INPUT NUM2
OUT
ADD R2,R0,X0                 ;STORE NUM2 IN R2
ADD R3,R2,R1
JSR LARGER
OUT
HALT
;*****DATA*****
IN_STR .STRINGZ "ENTER TWO SINGLE DIGIT INTEGERS: "
;*****SUBROUTINE*****
LARGER ST R1,SAVER1         ;SAVE R1
       ST R2,SAVER2         ;SAVE R2
       AND R0,R0,#0         ;CLEAR R0

;********DATA*********
SAVE R1 .BLKW 1
SAVE R2 .BLKW 1
.END
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to run both numbers through some sort of mask. Say you had:
SAVER1: 10001010
SAVER2: 01110010

If you AND them both against something like 10000000 it would show you that SAVER1 has a one in the most significant bit while SAVER2 does not. You could bit shift your mask as needed until you find the most significant bit. It'll get a bit more complicated if they both have the same first significant bit, but that's a place to start anyway.